# issue in calling css file in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp

How to call css or js file from

```
/app
    /webroot
          /bootstrap
                 /bootstrap.css
```

---

if i added

```
echo  $this->Html->css('bootstrap');
```

code in `view/Locale/default.ctp` its working fine .. but bootstrap.css file not taking from bootstrap folder .
If i copied bootstrap.css in `webroot/css` folder its working fine ..

I am fresher for cakephp . Can anyone help me to resolve issue

Comment: If you want to use Twitter Bootstrap from CakePHP you'd better use a proper plug-in that overrides the default helpers. You should be able one or more in the [plugin and packages directory](http://plugins.cakephp.org/).

Comment: actally i m using bootstrap theme.

Comment: how to use plugins in cake php .

Comment: [Plugins](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html). Alternatively, you can just read the installation instructions of the chosen plugin—you have to read them anyway and it might be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path that you provide in `$this->Html->css()` is the path of webroot, If you have a sub-folder under webroot, and the css file is in the sub-folder,you have to specify the sub-folder name, like this:

`$this->Html->css('bootstrap/bootstrap');`

Answer (score 1):

use this hope this Help

```
$this->Html->css('/bootstrap/bootstrap');
```